# Get FB friend chat status

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I'm upgrading my app graph API version to version 2.xx.

I have a game which in it I can chat with my online facebook friends or invite them to play if they are offline.
I get my facebook friend's list by calling the graph API with this:

FB.api(
  "/me/friends",
  function (response) {
     if (response && !response.error) {
        ....
     }
  });

In the new API, there is no field named 'online_presence' for the User object.
The data returns to me only contains the friend's name & id.
If I try to use FQL query, I get only users that are 'offline'.

Is there a way to find out the friend's facebook chat status?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> All friends_* permissions have been removed.

See the changelog https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

It isn't possible anymore. Sorry to tell that!